# Date Time greater than another table

Tags: mysql

Trying to set a clause where the created on date is greater than the talk start time. Both createdon and talkstarttime are from different tables. However, I get the error "The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than operator."

This part of the query is not working: 
Where t.[CreatedOn] > cd.[TalkStartTime

Thanks!

Comment: You can get the `TIME` part of a DATETIME value with the function [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time), but you should consider talks that begin shortly before midnight.

Comment: Did you actually *read the words* in the error message? They tell you exactly what is causing the problem, and it has nothing to to with the columns being in different tables; it clearly says the issue is with the greater than operator and two different column types (datetime and time). It's important to learn to read past the word "error" and actually read the error message; for the most part, they contain pretty clear details about the reason for the error.

Comment: Oh I see the syntax doesn't look like MySQL. It's rather sql-server with fields enclosed in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what VMAI stated, WHERE t.TIME(CreatedOn) > cd(talkStartTime) should work assuming when you run DESCRIBE  CreatedOn is defined as a DATETIME variable and talkStartTime is TIME variable. Good luck.